# Error Implementing Pandas Rolling Window Apply

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me understanding what I am doing wrong please?

```
def hmm(X):
    hmm_model = GaussianHMM(n_components = 3, random_state = 100,
                                covariance_type = "diag").fit(X)
    return pd.DataFrame(hmm_model.predict(X), X.index)


df.rolling(window=500, min_periods=500, axis=1).apply(hmm)
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your data? i.e. what is the structure of X, and what error message are you obtaining?

Comment: You're returning a dataframe on each rolling window. is that what you want? or do you just want to return a value?